# Dice Rolling Probability Space

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

I have a question in which the person asking has identified that the total sum of 11 comes up more often than a sum of 12 in the rolling of three dice and this is strange as they both have the same number of possible combinations of 3 numbers that make up 11 and 12.

Clearly 11 can be made up of combinations of : (6,4,1),(6,3,2),(5,5,1),(5,4,2),(5,3,3),(4,4,3). And I argued that when we have (a,b,c) with $a\ne b\ne c$, then we have 3! possible combinations, when two of a,b,c are equal then we have 3, and when we have $a=b=bc$ then we only have one combination.

I then argued that 12 has:
(6,5,1), (5,5,2), (4,4,4), (5,4,3), (3,6,3), (6,2,4) and because of the (4,4,4) triplet which only has one possible combination, the pr of a 12 is slightly lower than the possibiity of an 11.

The question asks me 'introduce a probability space' to tackle this question and I'm a bit confused as to how to approach this. What I've put together:

$\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^3$

$\mathscr F=\mathscr P(\Omega)$

$\mathbb P: \mathscr F\to[0,1]:\mathscr F (x)=\frac{card(x)}{216}$

where card is cardinality of the set x. Or should the function be a piecewise that depends on different values of a,b,c in the triplets?

Can I define the function like this instead?:

let the triplet (a,b,c) correspond to the outcome on the toss of each die, such that a,b,c$\in${1,2,3,4,5,6}

Let F be a function mapping the power set to [0,1] and x=(a,b,c).

Case1 (a=b=c):
f(x) = 1/216

case2 (a=b, a$n=$ c)
f(x) = 3/216

case 3 ($a\ne b \ne c$)

f(x) = 3!/216 = 6/216

Comment: For the sake of computing **the number of different combinations** that sum up to a certain value, the order might not matter (depending on how you define different combinations). But for the sake of computing **probability**, it does. The probability space is simply the set of all $216$ possible combinations.

Comment: @barakmanos I thought the probability space is $(\Omega,\mathscr F, \mathbb P)$, the set of all 216 possible outcomes is just describing the sample space $\Omega$ isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The dice are distinct objects. By coloring the dice, it might be easier see how the numbers are counted.  Here are the different ways to roll $11$ on $3$ dice:

```
RGB    RGB    RGB
641    461    335
632    452    326
623    443    263
614    434    254
551    425    245
542    416    236
533    362    164
524    353    155
515    344    146
```

Each of these has a $\frac1{216}$ chance of being rolled. Thus, an $11$ has a $\frac{27}{216}$ chance of being rolled.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've actually solved for this, my challenge atm is finding the probability space, that is, I have omega, I want to find the sigma field and probability measure for this experiment...

Comment: So you have the sample space, which is the $216$ different dice rolls, each with a probability of $\frac1{216}$. Above I have listed the outcomes meeting the criteria that the sum of the dice is $11$. You can do the same for $12$, or think of some more clever way. I listed them all so that it would be clear that `641` was to be counted separately from `416`, and `443` was to be counted separately from `434`, etc.

Comment: but how do you determine the probability measure and sigma field by knowing the sample space?... this is my question

Comment: The probability measure is discrete; $\frac1{216}$ given to each element of the probability space. The sigma *algebra* would be the power set of these $216$ different outcomes.